# ADF v2 - possible to get input of activity?

Tags: azure-data-factory

I know ADF could get the output of specific Activity, like this

```
activity('xxx').output
```

And could I get the input of specific Activity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such provision according to docs. Current activity input would be the output of previous activities right. You can use the same to store in a variable or parameter explicitly for your further use.

You can only view or copy inputs of an activity from pipeline run output or errors.

[image]

[image]